# Python Misses Parsing arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, url-parameters, urlparse

I wrote the following code to extract Get parameters from url like this:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

url = 'https://www.example.com/some_path?some_key=some_value&tt=new_value'
parsed_url = urlparse(url)
for val in parse_qs(parsed_url.query):
    print(val)
```

it works great with the above url but once I do url-encoding (which is still a valid url scheme as browsers accept it) like this:

```
https://www.example.com/some_path?some_key%3Dsome_value%26tt%3Dnew_value
```

My code doesn't output anything, why is that and how to fix?

Note: I know some of you may suggest doing url-decoding for the input but I don't think this will solve all cases, what if there was another encoding like for urls which is valid and should be parsed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

`parse_qs` decodes %-encoding in names and values, but it requires a literal `=` between query names and values and (by default) a literal `&` as separator.  You can check this in the source [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/urllib/parse.py) - `parse_qsl` does the work, and for example it does a string split on = to separate query names and values.

From your last sentence I don't think it's what you want, but `parse_qs(urllib.parse.unquote(parsed_url.query))` would work.